# The best way to initialize many object references to a default value in Java (code-style)

Tags: java, coding-style

What is the best way if I have many object references which NEED to be initiliazed (in a method) to a default value and I don't want to mess my code with many lines like:

```
String name = null;  
String address = null;  
String type = null;  
String edition = null;  
String year = null;
```

I sometimes use:

```
String name, address, type, edition, year;
name = address = type = edition = year = null;
```

Is there a better way? Is this way OK?

EDIT: These are instance variables. The purpose of this question is (as the tag indicates) to improve my code-style. I just want to produce the cleanest code and human readable as possible in when encountering this situation. What I am excepting as answer is some best-practices suggestions from experienced coders and I am not interested in explanation of how variable initialization of variables in java works as this is irrelevant for this question.

EDIT2: These variables need to be initialized. I am aware of basic rules of variables initialization in java.

Comment: Are those local variables? or instance fields?

Comment: Former way is more readable though.

Comment: Please give some context please such as telling us more about your motivation for worrying about this. It looks to me as if you're making a mountain out of a molehill. The key to good code is understandability, since 6 months or a year from now when you have to go back and debug it, it trumps most other considerations.

Comment: If they're locals, then why initialize them at all to `null`, seems error-prone. If instance variables, initialization is redundant.

Comment: I need to initialize them to null as these are used later and they might not be initialized (e.g. in try-catch or if  block) before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple assignments in one statement is considered bad quality and discouraged by the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html#547) (Section 10.4). I haven't seen multiple assignments in one statement in any serious commercial software development, because of the lack of readability. I strongly suggest to use separate assignments.

Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18525577/1884693) to an almost identical question for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Both ways act as same way after compile. But it is better to use first way since it is more readable and easy to understand. But you should use variables according to context.

Comment: Thank you for a relevant answer. I don't have that much experience to be able to look at it via the eyes of the next person reading code after me.

Answer (score 2):

Non-primitive Objects are by default `null`. So, this means that:

```
String name = null;
```

is equivalent with:

```
String name;
```

Note that this is only the case for class members. Local variables behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

Not only is the first easier to understand, the second one will create extra work in the case you decide once to change the initial value of one of the variables. Then you have to restructure the entire code. That’s not recommended. Further, keep in mind that this only works in the case of `null` and immutable objects and since you should not switch between different code styles you should use a pattern that works with all kinds of initial values. In other words: initialize the variables individually. This also will help if you want to turn one or some of the variables into a compile-time constant.

Comment: Thank you for a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), there is no need for you to assign `null` to object instance variables, `Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler`, in your case it will be set to `null` by default.

Answer (score 0):

The only declaration

```
String name, address, type, edition, year;
```

is enough.
Because in Java, String is a class and every String reference variable are initialized to null if none of the object is assigned to it.

```
String name, address, type, edition, year;
```

it means

```
String name = null;  
String address = null;  
String type = null;  
String edition = null;  
String year = null;
```

So no need to declare the objects like this and to initialize them explicitly to null.

Answer (score 0):

```
String name, address, type, edition, year=null;
```

Why dont you do like this. This makes your code cleaner as expected.

Comment: This way only the last variable gets initialized.